# php pasing values to another php

Tags: php, mysql

Here, I fetched a group of values from MySQL DB and displayed it in a list. I need to pass a particular value which is clicked by the user, just like Google does.

PHP snippet:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql1)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
        echo '<a href="#"><li>'.$row['shop_name'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
else{
    echo '<li>'.'No Results Found'.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: So, what's not working?

Comment: Well, think of what you'd put in the `href` of that `<a>` (which should be _inside_ the `<li>`. Some GET  / query variable holding the value of an identifier....

Comment: it s working, my problem is when i click to particular value, i need to pass that value to another php, so that i can do some other works based on that value there.

Comment: sorry, i am new to php, please correct me if there any mistakes in the above code

Comment: @Ansar then use AJAX or put something in the anchor href like the shop ID so that you can retrieve this through `$_GET`.

Comment: echo "<a href='your_script.php?$shop_id'><li>".$row['shop_name']."</li></a>"; try this out and get this variable in the your_script.php using $_GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql1)>0){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
        echo '<a href="pagename.php?field1='.$row['db_field1'].'&field2='.$row['db_field2].'"><li>'.$row['shop_name'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
else{
    echo '<li>'.'No Results Found'.'</li>';
} 

You can do like this.

Here 

pagename.php is page where you post info.
field1, field2 are names data to post.
$row['db_field1], $row['db_field2] are database fields.
```

Thanks!